# Why this code doesn't prompt the user to input their number?

Tags: python

I was trying to make a simple magic number code to guess what the computer has the number in it's mind. Tried to make it but it doesn't prompt an input like usual. Help is appreciated. p.s. this is my first time in stackoverflow.

```
import random

MagicNumber = random.randint(0,100)

InputtedNumber = eval(input("What number is the magic number?: "))

if InputtedNumber == MagicNumber:
    print("Yes that is the right number")
elif InputtedNumber < MagicNumber:
    print("A bit low, what number is the magic number?"))
else InputtedNumber > MagicNumber:
    print("A bit high, what number is the magic number?"))
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. Use `int()`.

Comment: Your code doesn't run due to the unmatched parentheses and incorrect syntax.

Comment: As @dfundako commented, this code has basic syntax errors.  Since you didn't mention this in your post, it seems like you're not even aware of them.  How are you running the code?  Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have mismatched parenthesis in your print statements - `print('a bit low..'))` should be `print('a bit low..')` (same for `a bit high..'`). Your current code will not even run.

You do not need to use `eval()` on `input()` - not only is it not safe (the user could enter commands to delete files, etc.) but it doesn't do what you want.

Try:

```py
try:
    InputtedNumber = int(input('What number is the magic number? '))
except:
    print('Invalid number!')
```

In the future, rather than using `eval` use a 'safe' version, such as `safe_eval()`, from `numpy` package.

Comment: Ah i see, i'll try your version. I just learnt to do this with eval by book so maybe the book tried to teach me in a way that is less effective but will improve what i should do in the next chapters. Thanks regardless :D